# What would be the best tool for automation testing of Excel Add-In?

Tags: excel-addins, automation-testing

I have created a Typescript based Excel Add-In and looking for an option to write automation testing for the same. (Like selenium for Web applications)

Tried pywin - Python based Winium driver usage

Due to some technical issues, I could not continue the same.